# Duplicates in a query result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, psql

How do we know whether a query contains duplicates or not? Under which circumstances a query result has no duplicates? (Without using DISTINCT operator, I mean).

Comment: Two circumstances that will get a non-duplicates result: using a GROUP BY clause and selecting only the columns you put in the GROUP BY clause, or selecting rows from a table with a PK (no duplicates allowed)

Comment: Please, explain how you need to know whether about duplicates - into result set (additional column), in some other variable or check it on some scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

A query result set has no duplicate tuples when:

1. you use `DISTINCT`
2. you `GROUP BY` a column and include only the grouping column and aggregates based on it in the resultset.
3. You `SELECT` a resultset that includes a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` column, with either no joins, an `INNER JOIN`, or a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the unique or primary key column on the *left side*.

There are probably other circumstances, but those are the main ones.

It'd help a lot if you explained *why* you're asking this and what problem you're trying to solve, btw.